# Google transliterate not working inside tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, transliteration

I tried to integrate **google transliteration** in to a project where the editor is **tinymce**. My **textarea**:

```
<textarea id="to_be_translated" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started) for integrating google transliterate and gave my textarea's id `to_be_translated` to the following line

> control.makeTransliteratable(['to_be_translated'])

and used the following code to implement Tinymce for the above textarea.

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>
```

When the page was loaded only Tinymce worked but the transliteration was not. I couldn't find the reason behind it. Could someone please suggest a way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs if you try to give your **textarea's id** to the google transliterate's code, while using Tinymce. There is no problem if you give your **textarea's id** without calling Tinymce to modify your textarea. But when you use Tinymce, it modifies your code and hide your textarea like this,

```
<textarea id="to_be_translated" style="width: 100%; display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>
```

So you won't be able to transliterate using the textarea's id.


### Solution


If you try to inspect the tinymce's editor window you will see an iframe like the one below with id similar to your textarea's id but with `_ifr` appended to it.

```
<iframe id="to_be_translated_ifr" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; display: block;"></iframe>
```

So now if you try to modify your google transliterate code like this,

> control.makeTransliteratable(['to_be_translated_ifr'])

google transliterate will start working along with Tinymce. So, in short, Tinymce will hide your textarea and use an iframe with id like your textarea's but with _ifr appended to it.
**In order to make the google transliteration work while using the Tinymce editor you have to give the iframe's id to the transliteration code instead of the textarea's id.**